# Theme old config settings still present?

Tags: shopware

In my custom theme (theme.json) I added a few new settings. Like this one:

```
"alice-h1-font-size": {
   "label": {
      "en-GB": "Product name font size (24-96)",
      "de-DE": "Productname schiftgröse (24-96)"
      },
      "type": "number",
      "custom": {
      "numberType": "int",
      "min": 24,
      "max": 96
       },
      "value": "48",
      "editable": true,
      "block": "aliceThemeTypography"
  }
```

Then I decided to change the key to "alice-product-name-font-size". The issue is that the old "alice-h1-font-size" is still present in the theme settings - under an unnamed section.

So, how do I get rid of the old version? I have run theme:refresh, cache:clear and theme:compile several times...

Magnus
[image: theme settings]

Comment: Did you try to reinstall the plugin?

Comment: No. I'm developing the theme on my local machine - and created it in the first place following the guide: bin/console theme:create (and so on).

Comment: I mean after changing your config, these settings might be created on plugin installation, not theme compile or anything else. So a reinstallation might fix the problem and remove the outdated config from database

Comment: Alright, I see. The only way, as I see it, is then to create a new theme from scratch and copy the theme.json. This seems odd. And according to the guides, running theme:refresh should re-read the theme.json file (and update the settings). Im lost.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case, that is still shown, because it is saved in the database. You can try to delete it manually and see whether it is still there.